# Firebase Data stream not visible. No data received in past 48 hrs.(React Native)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics, data-stream

I've integrated react native firebase analytics with custom events. I see data being present in GA, also in debug view I'm able to view all the events triggered. I'm unable to view the data in data stream.

GA Data stream

[image]

I get No data received in past 48 hrs. Is there any other configuration we need to do to view data in data stream?

I've been looking into debug view for testing and I do see events in debug view.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this status shows when there isn't any data being recorded because you have not finished setting up tags for your property.

If you are using a CMS or website builder that doesn't provide a field to enter your "G-" ID, you'll need to paste your Google tag into your website using your CMS's custom HTML feature.

- Sign in to your [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/web) account.
- Click [Admin](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6132368).
- At the top of the *Property* column, select your property.
- In the *Property* column, click **Data streams > Web**.
- Click the data stream for your website.
- Under *Google tag*, click **View tag instructions**.
- On the *Installation instructions* page, select **Install manually**:

  - On the screen, you’ll see the JavaScript snippet for your account's Google tag. Your Google tag is the entire section of code that appears, beginning with:
    `<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->` and ending with `</script>`

Paste your Google tag to your website using your CMS's custom HTML feature.

You could check this [page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153#stream&zippy=%2Cios-app-or-android-app%2Cadd-the-tag-to-a-website-builder-or-cms-hosted-website-eg-wordpress-shopify-etc:%7E:text=Set%20up%20data%20collection%20for%20websites) for the complete guide on setting up the data collection for websites.